# node js how to assign two collection data into a single object to render on views

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm creating a simple news article application for my own practices. So I created two schemas to do this in mongoose.
Now I'm trying retrieve data from those collection and trying to assign those values into a single object.
I tried to do this so many times and searched so many places but still couldn't find a better solution to do this in node js.

This is my get router to display the data on view:

```
app.get('/admin-area345', function(req, res){
    articles.find({}, function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            categories.findById(data[i].cat_id).then(function(cates){
                data[i]['cat_name'] = cates.catName;
                console.log(data);
                res.render('pages/admin/index', {
                    arts: data
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is my category model schema:

```
const catSchema = Schema({
    catName: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

This is my article schema:

```
const artSchema = Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    body: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String
    },
    cat_id: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

At last this is the view page to display the data retrieved from the mongoose collection. To do this I used EJS template as my view engine.

```
<%if(typeof(arts) != 'undefined'){%>
<div class="articles">
<%for(var i = 0; i < arts.length; i++){%>
    <h2><%=arts[i].title%> | <small><%=arts[i].cat_name%></small></h2>
    <p><%=arts[i].body%></p>
    <p>Added date - <%=arts[i].date%></p>
    <small>Added By - <%=arts[i].author%></small></br>
    <a href="/admin-area345/adminupdateart">Update Article</a></br>
    <a href="/admin-area345/admindelart">Delete Article</a></br>
<%}%>
</div>
<%}%>
```

I hope you guys will give me a better answer to do this easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should do your query with aggregate then easily you can modify your objects.So try this::**
*when we use find query to retrieve data from mongodb than we cannot update or change object.so use aggregate instead of find().*

```
app.get('/admin-area345', function(req, res){
    articles.aggregate([{'$match':{}]).exec(function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            categories.findById(data[i].cat_id).then(function(cates){
                data[i]['cat_name'] = cates.catName;
                console.log(data);
                res.render('pages/admin/index', {
                    arts: data
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer but can you please explain me little bit of the code. So does that line means   'articles.aggregate([{'$match':{}])' @vipin sharma

Comment: when you retrieve data from articles collection than you got data[array of object].if u want to modify data object " data[i]['cat_name'] = cates.catName;" than you want to add "['cat_name]'" field on your data object.but you cant modify this.so if u use aggregation query and than find data[array of object] than easily modify this.but i dont know what is difference between aggregate query and find query data[] array.so check aggregate query .